# AN: scale a grid in world axis without scaling objects

Tags: animation-nodes

I did a grid of spheres with distribute matrix and add it a rotation.
Next I want to scale the grid in the Z axis of the world (not the height of the grid).
But I don't want to scale de spheres with it.

I show you that what I tried and faild.

[image]

As you see the spheres are egg shaped and I want they stay round.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `Offset Matrix` with scale mode `Translation Only`. This option is available in advanced node settings.

[image]

Comment: How to open the avdanced node ?

Comment: Select offset matrix node and press U or u can find advanced settings on right N panel.

Comment: When I use your method the objects are not scaled. But the axis of scaling are the axis of the grid and not the world axis.